# Check box button not functioning on click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to give a checkbox button. Even though the button box and checkmark is shown,it's not functioning (not getting unchecked on click).Could anyone sort this out. I am new to HTML,CSS.

````
    ```
    <div class="col-sm-1 accept-box ">
            <input
              class=""
              type="checkbox"
              name="accept"
              value="accepted"
              checked
            /><label for=""></label>
          </div>

    input[type='checkbox'] + label {
    font-family: Proxima Nova,Open Sans,Corbel,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 1rem !important;
    width: 1rem !important;
    }

    input[type='checkbox']:checked + label::after {
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid var(--link-default);
    border-width: 0 0.125rem 0.125rem 0;
    content: '';
    height: 0.875rem !important;
    left: 0.35rem !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 0.5rem !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Did you add the script url of bootstrap? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label` must be provided `id` of the controlled element in its attribute `for`.

```css
div {
  /* optional styling. Just to show label */
  background-color: #000;
}

input[type='checkbox']+label {
  font-family: Proxima Nova, Open Sans, Corbel, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 1rem !important;
  width: 1rem !important;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked+label::after {
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid var(--link-default);
  border-width: 0 0.125rem 0.125rem 0;
  content: '';
  height: 0.875rem !important;
  left: 0.35rem !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 0.5rem !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-1 accept-box">
  <input id="accept" type="checkbox" name="accept" value="accepted" checked>
  <label for="accept"></label>
</div>
```